# Testing stateful UDFs in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am trying to test some stateful UDFs in my Scala Flink application following the docs:

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#unit-testing-stateful-or-timely-udfs--custom-operators

Based on that link, I've added the following dependencies to the `build.sbt` file:

```
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-test-utils" %  flinkVersion % Test,
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-runtime" %  flinkVersion % Test,
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-java" % flinkVersion % Test
```

But still, I cannot access the required utility classes such as `OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` (the class cannot be found).

FYI the scala version in my project is 2.12.11, whereas Flink is at v1.13.2. Am I doing something wrong? Any reasons why I cannot find those classes? Maybe the documentation is not correct?

Answer (score 2):

I added the `tests` classifier to the `flink-streaming-java` dependency in the `build.sbt` file and now it works:

```
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-java" % flinkVersion % Test classifier "tests"
```